# Lightbox Image Viewer,when thumbnail clicked fill image black background as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am new to AS3, and trying to do an image viewer similar to facebook style display, when clicked on a photo,but not sure where to start, and if what i am trying to do is pure As3 code. Some tips on where to start would be greatly appreciated.

Task:
1.) When image is clicked, enlarge the image to fit the screen width and display the image on a black background. 
2.) When the image is clicked again, reduce/zoom back out to where the page was before.

Thanks for your time and Help

```
import caurina.transitions.*;
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;


var full_tween:Tween;
var full_mc:MovieClip;
_contentHolder.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoscene);
function gotoscene(e:MouseEvent):void {
    //trace("over" + e.currentTarget.name);
    Tweener.addTween(e.currentTarget, { scaleX:thumbLarge, scaleY:thumbLarge, x:e.currentTarget.myx - e.currentTarget.width * Math.abs(thumbSmall - thumbLarge)/2, y: -e.currentTarget.width * Math.abs(thumbSmall - thumbLarge)/2, time:1 } );
    Tweener.addTween(e.currentTarget.blackBox, { alpha:thumbFadeIn, time: 1 } );
}
function outScrollerItem(e:MouseEvent):void {
    //trace("out" + e.currentTarget.name);
    Tweener.addTween(e.currentTarget, { scaleX:thumbSmall, scaleY:thumbSmall, x:e.currentTarget.myx, y:0, time:1 } );
    Tweener.addTween(e.currentTarget.blackBox, { alpha:thumbFadeOut, time: 1 } );
}

function fullLoaded(e:Event):void {
    full_mc = new MovieClip();
    addChild(full_mc);
    var my_loader:Loader = Loader(e.target.loader);
    full_mc.addChild(my_loader);


    my_loader.x = (stage.stageWidth - my_loader.width)/2;
    my_loader.y = (stage.stageHeight - my_loader.height)/2;

    my_loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fullLoaded);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried ? Some us some code, and we *will* help us. If you want people to do the job for you, you need to pay them.

Comment: Hi hi, yer i just not sure where to start at all, i just want some pointer just like 1 word or a line to show me which direction, thats all. But had been researching and now i think i suppose to look at Tween? I pasted some code above wonder if its something in that direction. I am not looking for all the codes i need, just a direction so i can start somewhere.